# How can i make a Vertical UISlider?

Tags: iphone, uislider

How can I make a vertical UISlider? I saw it in one of the applications and was trying to duplicate it. But seems difficult, does anyone know how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest approach is to simply rotate the slider. This can be done by using `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation` to create a transform and apply that to the slider's `transform` property. Just remember that the function takes radians.

Answer (score 0):

In case you use auto layout:

In your viewDidLoad, try:

```
UIView *superView = self.sizeSlider.superview;
[self.sizeSlider removeFromSuperview];
[self.sizeSlider removeConstraints:self.view.constraints];
self.sizeSlider.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
self.sizeSlider.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
[superView addSubview:self.sizeSlider];
```

It does not work with constraints, so the trick is to remove the constraints for your uislider.
You might have to resize it manually by setting its frame property.