# How to make a vertical UISlider?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, math, uikit, uislider

I want to use a vertical `UISlider`. I have no idea about how, so please help me.

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question asked yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369926/how-can-i-make-a-vertical-uislider

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You have to do this programaticaly. Assuming your UISlider is bound to a variable called `slider`, add this code in your viewDidLoad method in ViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGAffineTransform trans = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 0.5);
    slider.transform = trans;
}
```

Let me know if you need any more help on this..

Comment: This places the minimumValue end at the top. Use M_PI * -0.5 to place the minimumValue end at the bottom.

Comment: After transforming, how to track the rect of thumb position while sliding?

Comment: M_PI is the constant defined to represent the value of the mathematical constant Pi that you learned in school (22/7).

Comment: @ravinsp do you have any idea how to transform the thumb image the same way in order to appear the shadow on the correct position?

Answer (score 30):

As of Xcode 4.2, you can **sort of** do the same in Interface Builder.

- Create a slider
- Show the "Identity Inspector"
- Add a "User Defined Runtime Attribute"
- Set the key path to "layer.transform.rotation.z", the type as <del>"String" (</del>"Number" <del>won't allow floating point values)</del> (possible since Xcode 5) and the value to "-1.570795" (-π/2).

Unfortunately, it will still appear as horizontal in Interface Builder.

But you can position the center and don't need to create a custom class, so it might be useful enough in some cases. The effect is the same as ravinsp's code.

Comment: Actually you can put float into Number with comma (instead of dot).

Answer (score 7):

Swift 3:

```
slider.transform = slider.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(0.5 * Float.pi))
```

// Use 1.5 to invert the shadow of slider if you want

Answer (score 4):

In case you work with auto layouts:

In your viewDidLoad, try:

```
UIView *superView = self.sizeSlider.superview;
[self.sizeSlider removeFromSuperview];
[self.sizeSlider removeConstraints:self.view.constraints];
self.sizeSlider.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
self.sizeSlider.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
[superView addSubview:self.sizeSlider];
```

It does not work with constraints, so the trick is to remove the constraints for your uislider.
You might have to resize it manually by setting its frame property.

Comment: It does work with constraints if the only constraints you set are centerX, centerY, and width.

Answer (score 0):

Using an IBOutlet and setter observers.
If you want the max to be at the bottom, divide pi by positive 2

```
@IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider! {
    didSet {
        slider.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi / -2)
    }
}
```