# UIScrollView scrolling with indicator only

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, indicator

Intent (iPad): I've got a UIScrollView that's very sensitive to interaction so I'd like to have a large (finger sized) indicator that the user has to to use to scroll.

Problem: From what I can tell the only built-in UIScrollView indicator customisation is 'scrollIndicatorInsets' and 'Indicator Style', but neither of these effect size.

Does anybody know of a work around or am I going to have to make my own scrollbar from scratch?

Comment: You'll have to do this yourself. I'd reconsider your approach though as it's not a very iOS way of scrolling, users expect to be able to drag the scrollview itself.

Comment: What does your app do what would require an old-school desktop interface? Depending on what it is, there may be other options, including gestures caught before the scrollview views or splitting apart the interface. If you really do need it, check for CocoaPods for scrolling or for slider views.

Comment: @PeterDeWeese The short explanation of my app is a shopping list that's fast and interactive - tapping items on one view to add them to another or delete them. I find it annoying when I accidentally interact with something when scrolling and with my app it would be really inconvenient to accidentally delete something. Thank for the reply

Comment: You could try a [vertical `UISlider`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377030/how-to-put-uislider-vertical) as a fixed subview of the `UIScrollView`.  You'd still have to adjust it manually by implementing `UIScrollViewDelegate`, but it would probably be a lot easier than writing your own scroll bar.

Comment: Hmm. Why is it so touchy? Are you using touchDown instead of up? There are a lot of apps somewhat similar to what you describe that use a standard  scroll view. As long as you aren't using touchDown, you should be able to have the scroll gesture "win" the event.